# Custom footer bar in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

In my android app I am trying to develop this fixed footer bar layout. [Desired Footer Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rXkO.png)

I have written this code in my layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/appheader"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/size_2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/create_poll_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:src="@drawable/createpoll_new" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/size_3"
                android:text="Create"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_10" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/appheader"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/size_2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/corporate_corner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/brands" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/size_3"
                android:text="Brands"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_10" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fox_feed_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/feed_new_new" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/appheader"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/size_2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/leader_board_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/leaderboard_new" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/size_3"
                android:text="Leaders"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_10" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/appheader"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/size_2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/interest_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/interests_new" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/size_3"
                android:text="Interests"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_10" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But from this code I am getting this result.
[Resulted LAyout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu7s2.png)

Please someone help as I am new in android development.

Comment: You are complicating it with imageandtextview.. consider using textview with drawabletop

Comment: @Dhina That is correct I got it. But In my desired layout I want to show some part of my middle one image outside the layout..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/appheader"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/appheader"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/size_2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/create_poll_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/createpoll_new" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/size_3"
            android:text="Create"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_10" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/appheader"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/size_2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/corporate_corner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/brands" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/size_3"
            android:text="Brands"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_10" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fox_feed_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/feed_new_new" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/appheader"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/size_2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leader_board_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/leaderboard_new" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/size_3"
            android:text="Leaders"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_10" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/appheader"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/size_2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/interest_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/interests_new" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/size_3"
            android:text="Interests"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_10" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    //place your image and text view here

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

xml: Replace with your images/fonts/sizes/margins etc

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F86E3A"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Create" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Brands" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F86E3A"

            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Leaderboard" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Interests" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view" />
</FrameLayout>
```

drawable shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#D4CB47"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#3771B2" />
    <size android:width="80dp" android:height="80dp"/>
</shape>
```

Screenshot (used part of your image :P)

[image: Screenshot]